# Grammar of this language GLC

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to write the grammar of this language, the language is:

L = {$a^n b^n c^m d^m$ for $n > 0$ and $m >= 0$}

Which of the grammars generates the language?

$V$ = ${A, B, C}$

$∑$ = ${a, b, c, d}$

$R$ = ${}$

$S$ = ${A}$

What is the rule that can be applied in R?

I tried to set up the rule this way, but I believe it is not correct :(

{A -> B, A -> BC, B -> aBb, C -> cCd, B -> ab, C -> cd}, A}

Can you help me?

Comment: Please show you have attempted to work on this homework. Instead we will consider that you want us to do all the work, which is not profitable, and the question will be eventually closed...

Comment: @JeanMarie I tried to set up the rule this way, but I believe it is not correct :(  can you help me?

{A -> B, A -> BC, B -> aBb, C -> cCd, B -> ab, C -> cd}, A}